# Creating a mongo user with access to listCollections on a particular database

Tags: mongodb

I've created a user with the role `readWrite` using:

```
use reporting
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "reportsUser",
    pwd: "12345678",
    roles: [
       { role: "readWrite", db: "reporting" }
    ]
  }
)
```

which I thought would give it access to `listCollections` as described on https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/ . However, as soon as I turned on `security.authorization` in my `/etc/mongod.conf` file, that command stopped working - with the error:

```
command listCollections requires authentication' on server x.x.x.x:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "command listCollections requires authentication", "code" : 13, "codeName" : "Unauthorized" }
```

Any ideas what permission / role I need to do to allow this command?

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem. It works for me when I add `--authenticationDatabase admin` with `mongo -u admin -p password`